xamarin forms: ERROR "make sure the project was compiled before archiving xamarin forms"
When I want to create an APK from my Android project I get the following error message.

I've tried the following things to make sure the project is archived

Clean the projects one by one and their files
Clean the entire solution and compile the solution

When I archive the message is still the same

You can first check whether you can successfully generate an apk by using a new Xamarin Forms project template. In addition, the language of VS in the screenshot is not English. It is recommended to switch to English and check the error information.

Please [edit] your question and remove the ALLCAPS. This is considered harsh.

Did you check if your Android project is included in release build configuration? (Right click on solution, Build configuration)
